# About Array Initialisation

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone explain why i cannot use `array={a,b};`  :

```
public class Example {
 private final String a;
 private final String b;
 public final String[] array;

 public Example(){
  a="test";
  b="text";
  //String [] c = {a,b}; This is fine
  //array=c;
  array={a,b}; // this line throws an Exception
 }
}
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression
    at Example.<init>(Example.java:21)
    at hello.main(hello.java:26)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes in case of initializing an array using `{..}`, the *declaration* and *initialization* should be done at the same time.

Well, marking `array` as `final` complicates things.. You will not be able to initialize it later (you will have to do it inside the constructor) . Your code will not compile.

Yes you could use : `arr = new String[5];` in your constructor to initialize your array.

Comment: It is in the default constructor

Comment: @CodeCat - Hadn't seen that.. My bad .. Edited my answer :).. *Lashane*'s answer will work as well :)

Answer (score 2):

you should initialize array, like this:

```
array = new String[] {a,b};
```